# EF 4.2 Code First Stored Procedure Model Change Bug

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF 4.2 Code First and I added a new bool column 'Archived'. I am getting the error below on a page that is mapping stored procedures. Is there a way to re-sync the db table and the class without wiping out the database?

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Context.Pattern'.
>   A member of the    type, 'Archived', does not have a corresponding
>   column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: Where did you add column? Into entity class? Did you add it into procedure and table?

Comment: I added the column in the entity class and in the database table. I also updated the entity mapping class to have this column. I does not throw the error until the stored procedure is called. Is there a cached data reader that the stored procedure wrapper utilizes?

Comment: You should post your SP mapping class code

Comment: The issue was missed mapping in the stored procedure. I could have sworn it was there last night... Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should write an answer and accept it, to remove question from list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding a missing column in the stored procedure. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: As your issue is resolved by procedure described in answer, you need to mark answer as accepted, this way question is still on http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Comment: Sorry for being such a newb on the site. Done.